# Storing a Video blob in Firebase with custom Name attribute, returns Undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

The problem is all my Collections Documents are referring to the same blob file because each upload replaces the existing Storage blob.

I think I need to assign a Name to the Blob to store a New Entry each time an upload happens.

Trying to assign Name with Math.random() however has not worked. Suggestions?

```
import { useParams, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
const { productID } = useParams();

async function handleSubmitUpload() {
        if (recordedChunks.length) {
            const promises = [];
            const blob = new Blob(recordedChunks, {Name: Math.random()}, {type: "video/webm"});


            const reviewRef = await storage().ref(`prodReviews/${blob.Name}`)
            const uploadTask = await storage().ref(`prodReviews/${blob.Name}`).put(blob);
            await promises.push(uploadTask);
          
          
            const videoUrl = await reviewRef.getDownloadURL();
            const timestamp = new Date();

            await firestore
                .collection("products")
                .doc(productID)
                .collection("productReviewClips")
                .add({videoUrl, userID: auth.currentUser.uid, createdDate: timestamp }) 

               
                history.push(`/product/${productID}`);

                setRecordedChunks([]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You just don't have `productID` defined anywhere (at least in the code snippet provided in question)?

Comment: Yes it is defined elsewhere. But the problem is with the Naming of the blob file from the const blob = new Blob(recor....

Comment: I believe this Blob Naming problem maybe is isolated to this function. This is just a problem with storage.

Comment: I just don't see `productID` defined in scope of this function. Are you sure that the function can access it? Try adding `console.log(projectID)`  at the start of function.

Comment: I attached an image in the Firebase Developers Discord

Comment: Try `const blob = new Blob(recordedChunks, {type: "video/webm"});` and then generating a random ID using Firestore: `const randomId = firestore.collection("test").doc().id` Now you use this randomID in place of `blob.Name` while uploading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Blob()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob) constructor seems to take only 2 parameters but you are passing 3. You can use either Firestore SDK or [UUID](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) to generate random IDs and use them as file names as shown below:

```
const blob = new Blob(recordedChunks, {type: "video/webm"});

// Get a random ID 
const randomId = firestore.collection("test").doc().id

// Upload to Firebase Storage
const reviewRef = await storage().ref(`prodReviews/${randomId}`)
```